# How To Convert A Set Into Polar Coordinates For Integration?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

how do i calcute this set into polar coordinates for my integrals?
Let

$$ D_a,_b = {(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2:x \leq0, y \geq0, a^2 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq b^2} $$

Thanks!

Function to calculate with:
$$ f(x) = 3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2} $$ so i  started with: $$ \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \int_a^b 3 \sqrt{r^2cos(θ)^2+r^2sin(θ)^2} dr dθ$$
my current solution is:
$$  -\frac{3}{4}\pi(a^2-b^2) $$

Comment: This is good progress. Please see update2 to my answer below.

Comment: Please see another update, you did not incorporate my second remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a geometric approach. Your region is an annulus (area between two circles) with radii $a<b$, limited to the 2nd quadrant. Hence, $a \le r \le b$, but can you compute the range for $\theta$?

---

An algebraic way to see this is to note that $r^2=x^2+y^2$, so the last constraint reads $a^2 \le r^2 \le b^2$, and since $r>0$ we must have $a \le r \le b$.

Now use $x \le 0, y \ge 0$ to fix the range for $\theta$. Can you finish?

---

**UPDATE**

After settling our discussion in the comments, you end up with the following double integral:
$$
\iint_{D_{a,b}} f(x,y) \ dx \ dy
 = \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \int_a^b f(r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta)\ r \ dr \ d\theta
$$

---

**UPDATE 2**

Your approach is good but:

- you can simplify the expression under the root, note that $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$ and $\sqrt{r^2} = r$ since $r>0$
- when you convert $dx \ dy$ to polar, you get $r \ dr \ d\theta$ (not $dr \ d\theta$ as you seem to)

---

**UPDATE 3**

Now you have $f(x,y) = 3\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 3r$ and so you get
$$
\iint_{D_{a,b}} f(x,y) \ dx \ dy
 = \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \int_a^b (3r) \cdot r \ dr \ d\theta
 = \frac{\pi}{2} \left[ b^3 - a^3 \right]
$$

Comment: im not sure but i think i will have $$ \int_0^{2pi} \int_a^b $$ ?

Comment: @Eiden not quite. You are taking all possible values for $\theta$ which will use all four quadrants. You only need the second one -- where $x \le 0$ and $y \ge 0$. What range of angles does that correspond to?

Comment: oh that has a range of 90 ° and so i only need pi/2 ?

Comment: @Eiden closer now. That does have range of $90^\circ$, but if you go $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$ you describe the first quadrant. Can you describe the second?

Comment: i guess    π/2≤θ≤π ? and the other 2 are the same only for negative values ?

Comment: @Eiden now you got it. Indeed $\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi$. Not sure about what *the other two* mean in your question.

Comment: Thats a calculation for an 2 dim Integral but i should use polar coordinates. So one integral for θ and one for the radius

Comment: @Eiden please see the update

Comment: also see my update !

Comment: i have added a solution. i hope it is right =D

Comment: Thank You! I have the right solution now. Thanks for leading me to the answer and not just giving it to me =)

Comment: @Eiden you are welcome